# Origin 'http://XXXXXXXX:xxxx' has been blocked by CORS policy .NET Core and Angular

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a frontend Application that is built in Angular and it is providing GET,POST requests to the API server built in dotNet Core 2.0 adding the headers `withCredentials: true` on every request, I have tried configuring CORS in multiple ways mentioned below but none of them seem to perfectly work.

I tried adding CORS policy by using the specified way i.e.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
              {
                  options.AddPolicy("MyCustomCorsPolicyName",
                              builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://YourDomainName/")
                                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                                      .AllowCredentials()
                              );
              });
```

but i got the Access blocked error for both GET and POST requests. Then I tried to write a custom CORS Middleware which was working for GET Requests but was giving an error of `401 Unauthorized` while doing a `POST` request. Here's my implementation of the CORS Custom Middleware:

```
public class CorsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

public CorsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
{
    _next = next;
}

public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{

    string origin = httpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString().TrimEnd(new char[]{'/'});
    Console.Write(new[] { (string)httpContext.Request.Headers["Origin"] });
    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://XXXXXXXX:yyyy");
    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name");
    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    if (httpContext.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {   
        return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Ok");
    }
    return _next(httpContext);
}
}
// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class MiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCorsMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CorsMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

I figured that it had to do with the OPTIONS preflight request that is sent before POST request.I tried adding Authorize attribute globally. To do that I added the following after the services.AddCors() method above in the ConfigureServices() method

```
  services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Then, I added this little nugget to allow anonymous requests:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

and

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

and also set

```
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
```

in `launchSettings.json`
but still got the same 401 Unauthorized error while doing a POST request from my Angular frontend.

I even installed the [IIS CORS Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference) and removed all the CORS checks in my application code.
My `web.config` file looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
<cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
 
  <add origin="http://XXXXXXXXX:yyyy/"
       allowCredentials="true"
       maxAge="120">
    <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true">
      <add header="Content-Type" />
      <add header="Accept" />
    </allowHeaders>
    <allowMethods>
      <add method="GET" />
      <add method="POST" />
      <add method="PUT" />
      <add method="OPTIONS" />
      <add method="DELETE" />
    </allowMethods>
    <exposeHeaders>
      <add method="GET" />
      <add method="POST" />
      <add method="PUT" />
      <add method="OPTIONS" />
      <add method="DELETE" />
    </exposeHeaders>
  </add>
 
</cors>
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApplication_WebAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and installed the IIS CORS Module x64 on my server, but after this change the CORS Configuration doesn't seem to work at all.

Can you help me as to how I can configure my API server to handle CORS request in a good way?

Comment: Is the Angular frontend hosted at `http://YourDomainName/`. If the sender domain doesn't match then CORS will block the call - you shouldn't need a custom CORS middleware unless you are doing something unusual. I would remove the middleware and start again with just the `AddCors` calls.

Comment: Yes you are right. I shouldn't have used the custom middleware. Now I have tried implementing the CORS using default implementation (using AddCors()) and my Get call are working fine now but POST calls getting an error of 401 Unauthorized.